# SqlAlchemy raw SQL queries strange errors

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, db2

I´ve been facing some weird issues when studding SQL raw queries using SqlAlchemy.

```
sqlstr = 'SELECT "City" from CHICAGO_SCHOOLS;'
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text(sqlstr))
    print (result.all())
```

The query above returns hundreds of "Chicago" as results. So I just tried to get unique results:

```
sqlstr = 'SELECT DISTINCT "City" from CHICAGO_SCHOOLS;'
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text(sqlstr))
    print (result.all())
```

Now, all I got is a weird error :

> Exception: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664]
> SQL0134N  Improper use of a string column, host variable, constant, or
> function "City".  SQLSTATE=42907

At first I thought it was somehow related to the `DISTINCT` set quantifier. So I tried the same query with another column.

```
sqlstr = 'SELECT DISTINCT "School ID" from CHICAGO_SCHOOLS;'
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text(sqlstr))
    print (result.all())
```

And in this query I got all expected results.
I am not being able to truly understand what is wrong!

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741539/db2-error-improper-use-of-a-string-column-host-variable-constant-or-function) answer, it could be that `city` is of a type not allowed in grouping. `DISTINCT` probably groups

Comment: Wow, it makes sense! Its a CLOB type!
Where can I find information about this kind of restrictions (types that does not allow indexing)?

Comment: (unrelated note), do you really have separate school tables for each city? Consider one single schools table.

Comment: Lol. Such tables are from sample data available on internet. I got them from a course about python handling db2 database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the column type. It was a CLOB type and that does not allow use of DISTINCT. Thanks to HoneyBadger